# How to run multi input keras model separately?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a multi input keras model that looks like the one in the below figure. The inputs are (244, 244, 3). I can't run it on my computer as I run out of memory. Is there a way to run each channel separately and then concatenate their output and continue the training?

Here the code I used to create the model:

```
def create_multi_channel_cnn():
    channel_1 = create_model(input_shape=(244, 244, 3))
    channel_2 = create_model(input_shape=(244, 244, 3))
           
    # combine the output of the two branches
    combined = concatenate([channel_1.output, channel_2.output])

    x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(combined)
    x = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[channel_1.input,  channel_2.input], outputs=x)

    return model
```

Each channel has the following layers:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
```

[image]

Comment: If you separate the channels you are going to have to train 3 different CNN models. But they will end up with three different set of weights as the weights of a multi-input CNN need to be trained on all the channels together. Otherwise you end up with a different model for each channel. You can try converting to grayscale and see if your memory can handle it and if you get good accuracy. If the memory is not enough --> buy a gpu :) if it runs you might consider training 3 different models for each channel and do some kind of [ensemble learning] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)

Comment: @JacoSolari so I need to train each channel separately as a model save them, then load them and stack them together.

Comment: That is one way to do it, you can read about model ensembling to find what suites you best. But again, keep in mind that this procedure is NOT equivalent to training a multi-input CNN on a 3-channel image set and you will have different performances/results (not necessarily worse ;) ML is a pretty empirical science so there's nothing wrong in trying different approaches, as long as they work).

Comment: @JacoSolari thanks for the information. I've found a similar work where they had 32 channels on a GTX 1080Ti, so I assumed that they must have used some kind of what I was asking for in the beginning.

Comment: For info, I'm using a GPU, I have a Quadro T2000.

Comment: mmm it sounds weird that you cannot load 244x244 rgb images on that GPU (looks pretty good and new). I worked with similar hardware on larger images with no problem. Maybe is something with your code/settings. WHat batch size are you using for training?

Comment: @JacoSolari I'm using a  `batch_size = 32`. I hope I'm not doing something wrong. The GPU has a memory of `3911MiB`

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller batch size say of 5?

Comment: @JacoSolari I've just tried that and it worked with just some warnings :  `(GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.28GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.`

Comment: there you go :) then maybe try to downsize your images and use a smaller batch size?

Comment: OK, I'll try that and see. Thanks.

Comment: ok let me know if it works. Also please consider upvoting some of the comments if you find them useful :)

Comment: @JacoSolari I was able to run the model with a batch size of 3. Thanks for that. Now I'm facing another issue.  Can you take a look at my newest post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105553/getting-an-error-with-a-multi-input-keras